# phantomjs+express not working and get errors

Tags: javascript, express, phantomjs

This is my app.js that performs web scraping:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path=require('path');
const express = require('express');
var phantomjs = require('phantomjs')
const phantom = require('phantom');

server.post("/"  ,async (req,res) =>{
const instance = await phantom.create();
    const page = await instance.createPage();
await page.open('mytestwebsite.com', function(status) {
data = page.evaluate(function(){
a = document.getElementsByClassName("class1").innerText;
b = document.getElementsByClassName("class2").innerText;
return data= {
    a,
    b,
}
});
 console.log(data);
instance.exit();
});
});
```

I am getting the following error:

```
info: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ',' 
info:   undefined:7 in Function  
info:   phantomjs://code/index.js:315  
info:   :0 in parse  
info:   phantomjs://code/index.js:307 in read
```

Comment: can i know what i miss

Comment: Hi Xone, welcome to the site.  It would help if you could add further information to your question.  What is your program trying to do?

Comment: i want to scrap data from  another website using phantomjs